# setting config.action_controller.perform_caching = true breaks routes in rails 3.2.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am experiencing extremely strange behaviour in Rails 3.2.1

I have some resources that do not have show actions.
For example:

```
resources :homes, :except => [:show]
```

In my controller I say:

```
  def update
    @domain = Domain.where(:domain => request.domain.split('.').first).first    
    @home = Home.find(params[:id])
    if @home.update_attributes(params[:home])
      expire_page :action => :index
      redirect_to(admin_path(@domain), :notice => "Updated.") 
    else
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end
```

and all is hunky dory in development.

But in production rails consistently tries to redirect to (the non existent) show action, despite the obvious redirect_to. It's as if this method is ignored totally. In fact I can try and redirect to any path in the app and it will be ignored. As soon as I set perform_caching to false in production.rb the routes begin to behave as expected again! Any ideas why this is happening and how I can make it stop!? Obviously I could turn off caching, but I need the pages to be cached for performance reasons.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you post where `admin_path` is defined in your routes file? Index routes do not take a parameter, yet you're passing in a `Domain` object?? It looks like a `show` route to me.

Comment: Hi there! It is routing to a show action (in the admin controller) The route is defined normally as:   resources :admin, :only => [:index, :show]

Comment: On closer inspection I think this problem has more to do with Nginx than it does with Rails. I have posted a related question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/358263/routing-non-get-requests-to-passenger-in-nginx